# django_microsoft_auth reply URL issues and other questions

Tags: django, azure, authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory

I am trying to use the django_microsoft_auth package. I have some questions and issues:

1. When I try and login I get `AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in
   the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the
   application` - how do I debug or fix this?
2. The docs say `If you want multiple Site objects and generate authorize URL when accessing your site from multiple domains, you must not set a SITE_ID` But if I do not set the SITE_ID my app will not run at all - I get Site matching query does not exist. So I am running with SITE_ID = 1. Is that an issue?
3. The login with microsoft link is only on the admin page - how would I get that on my app's main login page?

Comment: Not familiar with django. But for the first question, when you are registering the Azure AD App, it will ask for a Redirect URI. This must match the absolute URL of your microsoft_auth:auth-callback view. By default this would be https://<your-domain>/microsoft/auth-callback/.

Comment: Thanks. I got past this point, and now am getting `An invalid state variable was provided. Please refresh the page and try again later.`

Comment: Now getting this: `Scope has changed from "profile openid email" to "User.Read profile openid email"`

Comment: I found the error is coming from oauthlib and by commenting out the call to validate_token_parameters I can get this to work. Obviously that is not a good solution. Anyone have any thoughts on this?